# No se pueden establecer encabezados después de enviarlos al cliente

Tags: nodejs, typescript, postman

estoy teniendo este problemita en el código de mi API, estoy enviando unas respuesta en un método que puede retornar un json con datos o un mensaje

Este es el error que estoy teniendo:
[image: Error en consola]

este es el codigo del metodo:

```js
public async obtenerProductsbyStoreTagIDAll(
    req: Request,
    res: Response
  ): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const idtagstore = req.params.id;
      const tag = await pool.query(
        `SELECT * FROM ut_tags_stores WHERE id=$1 AND estado=1`,
        [idtagstore]
      );
      if (tag.rowCount > 0) {
        const objtag = tag.rows;
        const tienda = await pool.query(
          `SELECT t.* FROM st_store as t INNER JOIN st_tags_store as tgs ON tgs.idststore=t.id
      WHERE iduttagstores=$1 AND t.estado=1 AND tgs.estado=1`,
          [idtagstore]
        );
        if (tienda.rowCount > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < tienda.rows.length; i++) {
            objtag[0]["tiendas"] = tienda.rows;
            const productos = await pool.query(
              `SELECT * FROM st_products WHERE idststore = $1 AND estado=1 ORDER BY nombrearticulo ASC`,
              [tienda.rows[i].id]
            );
            if (productos.rowCount > 0) {
              for (let j = 0; j < productos.rows.length; j++) {
                objtag[0]["tiendas"][i]["products"] = productos.rows;
              }
            } else {
              res.send({
                status: "402",
                message: "La tienda no tiene ningun producto",
              });
            }
          }
        } else {
          res.send({
            status: "402",
            message: "El tag no esta asociado a ninguna tienda",
          });
        }
        res.status(200).json(objtag);
      } else {
        res.send({
          status: "402",
          message: "El tag no existe",
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.send({ status: e.status, message: e.message });
    }
  }
```

estoy forzando con un id de tag que no existe para forzar y emular los posibles errores y en el postman me retorna bien pero me sale el error de la primera imagen

Respuesta en el postman:

[image: Respuesta en postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy viendo este trozo de código:

```
...
    } else {
      res.send({
        status: "402",
        message: "El tag no esta asociado a ninguna tienda",
      });
    }
    res.status(200).json(objtag);
...
```

Como ves, después de la llamada `res.send(...)` no hay ningún return, con lo que el método se sigue ejecutando y acabas llegando a `res.status(200).json(objtag);`, que intenta modificar una respuesta que ya se ha mandado.

Comment: eso estuve probando ahora y si, es cierto, gracias man.

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta (con el check que hay ahí al lado) para dejar la pregunta *respondida*